# Facebook JS+FLASH SDK: Works on IE not in FF, Chrome

Tags: javascript, flash, facebook

I have a facebook application developed with a mixture of the PHP, JS, and AS3 SDKs.

The application works perfectly on IE but it hangs on other browsers (FF,Chrome)

IN FF debug console I see an error message:

> Empty string passed to
>   getElementById(). 
>   swf is null (92 out
>   of range 62)

This error happens just after calling:

```
Facebook.init( APP_ID, _handleInit );
```

The callback it's never fired.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I am working on a similar project. The Open Graph SDK for AS3 does pretty much all you can do with the PHP SDK. If you are trying to user PHP to communicate with Facebook and pass the data to AS3 via JS, you may consider using the AS3 SDK.

Comment: I use the PHP sdk to mange general flow of the app and also manage invites and the such. The app itself is a flash app, and uses the AS3 sdk, which is only a bridge for the JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the culprit.

The Facebook api needs a reference to the embedded SWF object. Since I was using SWFObject, I needed to pass two parameters: id for IE and name for Chrome/Mozilla Browsers.

Simple as that...

Comment: can you please clarify, I'm having the same problem, pass to SWF object or flash? my javascript code is swfobject.embedSWF("Preloader.swf", "flashContent", "810", "610", "10.0.0", null, null, params, {name:"flashContent"});

Comment: You need to modify the attributes parameter, and add the id => {name:'flashContent', id:'flashContent'}

Comment: I just tried this but still not working with Chrome and IE, though I didn't have any issues with Safari and Firefox, any other advise.

Comment: uhm...not without looking at some markup/code. Perhaps the id is not set to the proper value (flashContent)